# No change on APK

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle

I tried to generate an APK with android studio. I used it to write react-native code.
The first compilation was great, I have the .apk file, signed, without difficulties.

This time when I try to generate a new apk file I don't see the changes in the program.

I tried to :

- clean gradle (gradlew clean; gradlew cleanBuildCache,...)
- clean cache of Android studio (files > invalidate caches)
- clean cache on Android phone
- desinstall app on the phone
- delete old file .apk (on computer and on phone)

Without change. I loose many time on this issue. Please, help me...

Thanks.

Comment: did you re-build the react-native code ?

Comment: Android studio : build > clean Project : done
Android studio : build > build APK : done
on terminal : react-native run-android : done

Not tested android studio : build > rebuild project

Comment: if you just `run-android`, you don't need to build the APK. It should load on your phone without needing to build the actual apk right away (yourself)

Comment: If you want to rebuild your app into a release `.APK` follow this guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I need an APK file to install the app' on a phone. I used run-android on my dev' phone ;)

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android